# Tridion 2011 Content Porter Installation Problem

Tags: content-porter-2009

I am trying to install Content Porter 2009 SP1 however I keep encountering a problem where the client installer crashes upon pressing 'Settings','Next' or 'Cancel'. The Content Porter icon was added to the Tools panel of the Content Manager successfully upon initial install of CP SP1, and when I click it to install the Content Porter client software the installer opens, but when I click 'Next' the installer window crashes yielding the following error "SDL Content Porter has stopped working".

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Content Porter SP1 to no avail. We have also contacted Tridion Support to ensure that the Content Porter license was valid, which they confirmed it was. I am running Windows 2008 R2 and Tridion 2011 SP1. Any ideas?

**-- UPDATED --**

Still encountering the problem, here is a post of the log. I've installed the cumulative hotfix as well as the CM_2011 hotfix, neither had any success in fixing the problem.

```
   7/3/2013 5:11:56 PM  [Critical]  Could not load type 'Tridion.Localization.LocalizationException' from assembly 'Tridion.Common, Version=6.1.0.25, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53'.   at Tridion.Localization.Wrapper.Impl.StringResourceManager.GetString(String name)
      at Tridion.Localization.Wrapper.StringResourceManager.GetString(String name)
      at Tridion.ContentPorter.Presenters.WizardNavigatorPresenter.UpdateTitleAndDescription()
      at Tridion.ContentPorter.Presenters.WizardNavigatorPresenter.ShowNextStep()
      at Tridion.ContentPorter.GuiClient.MainForm.MainForm_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
      at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
      at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)



   7/3/2013 5:11:57 PM  [Critical]  The given key was not present in the dictionary.   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
      at Tridion.ContentPorter.GuiClient.MainForm.Tridion.ContentPorter.Presenters.IWizardNavigatorView.ValidateCurrentStep()
      at Tridion.ContentPorter.Presenters.WizardNavigatorPresenter.ValidateCurrentStep()
      at Tridion.ContentPorter.Presenters.WizardNavigatorPresenter.Next()
      at Tridion.ContentPorter.GuiClient.MainForm.btnNext_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
      at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
      at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)



   7/3/2013 5:11:57 PM  [Critical]  Could not load type 'Tridion.Localization.LocalizationException' from assembly 'Tridion.Common, Version=6.1.0.25, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53'.   at Tridion.Localization.Wrapper.Impl.StringResourceManager.GetString(String name)
      at Tridion.ContentPorter.GuiClient.Program.OnGuiUnhandedException(Object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.OnThreadException(Exception t)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProcException(Exception e)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnThreadException(Exception e)
      at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
      at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
      at Tridion.ContentPorter.GuiClient.Program.Main()
```

Comment: Log files will be generated and can be found at My documents/Content Porter. If you locate them add it along with the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What version of Content Porter are you trying to work with?  If you're using Content Porter 2009 SP1 with Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1, then you will have this issue.  CP 2009 SP1 is only good up to Tridion 2011 GA.  For Tridion 2011 SP1, you need to be on CP 2009 SP2.  Is it possible you grabbed the wrong installable from your company's archive?

The CP 2009 SP1 installer does not include `Tridion.Common` DLL in the Content Porter bin folder, so CP then finds a match in the GAC.  However, as Harald hinted in his answer, it's the wrong version.  It is missing classes, such as the `Tridion.Localization.LocalizationException`; which I'm guessing were present in the pre-2011 SP1 HR1 versions of Tridion.

If you install Content Porter 2009 SP2, you'll see that it places its own version of `Tridion.Common` file in the bin folder, which is different from the one in the GAC and your issue should be no more :)

Answer (score 9):

You might first need to try the following.

- If you are running Content porter 2009 SP1 with Tridion 2011 SP1, you should consider the hotfix indicated [HERE](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/1360/545).
- Check if your Content porter server is started in your content manager box
- Initiate content porter from the content manager box (from the above I understand that it is Windows 2008 R2), you should not encounter any issues. If you do, uninstall content porter client and try again. Uninstall instructions can be found [HERE][2]. You can check the logs that will added to your user name/ My Documents as suggested by @Ajo.
- If the above is unsuccessful, it might be typically due to permissions associated with your C:/Windows/Temp folder. Steps are indicated [HERE](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/1360/545)

I hope it helps!

Comment: After trying your suggestions I have updated the post.

Answer (score 5):

I have noticed that there are two different Tridion.Common.dll files.
One exists in the GAC (if you are working on a tridion server), and one exists in the Content Porter installation folder (start->sdl tridion->content porter program folder)
You'll see that the dll in the GAC has version 6.1.0.25, while the one in the CP folder has version 2.0.139.0.

In your log file, it is stating it's using the 6.1.0.25 dll, which (i think) is the wrong one.
Maybe something has gone wrong during installation, or something is wrong with user rights ?