# Purge Tool disabled due to access denied error

Tags: 2011, iis7, purgetool

Currently we're about to do some maintenance for a client, but we noticed that on both the test CMS and the Live CMS the access is denied when using the Purge Tool application. This is what event viewer returns:

```
Unable to Initialize TDSE object. Access is denied for the user <CLIENT>\ADM. Error Code: 0x80040302 (-2147220734) Call stack: Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.LoadAccessToken(String,IEnumerable`1,IEnumerable`1) Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.LoadAccessToken(String,String) Tridion.ContentManager.Session..ctor(String,String,UserContext) Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.SystemFacade.InitializeUserContext(UserContext,String,String) UtilitiesTDS.GetUserContext TDSE.Initialize
```

I've followed the instruction posted here [Access is denied for the user IIS APPPOOL\(pool name)](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/access-is-denied-for-the-user-iis-apppool-pool-name) but the app pool is set to network service and i have all read/write access to the folders mentioned there. I've also asked someone with the highest read/write access to try and start the application from his side, but the same thing happens only with a different user.

Any tips?

Comment: When you try to login to the UI using the <CLIENT>\ADM user, does that work, and is this user a SDL Tridion CMS Administrator?

Comment: You need to add the user `<CLIENT>\ADM` to Impersonation Users and also add the user using 'aspnet_regiis -pa "TridionRsaKeyContainer" <CLIENT>\ADM`. Restart all tridion services incl COM+.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not about file system access. When you get a message saying you can't initialize TDSE because access is denied for user... this is Tridion's own security system at work. In other words, the user who is executing the purge tool needs to be a Tridion user. In addition, the user will need to have sufficient permissions to do whatever actions you intend to do with the purge tool. In practice, this means a system administrator user.

Comment: Apparantly, I've logged in with RDP under the Administrator account, but without a domain prefix. Looks like this wasn't enough to start it, and you really need to be logged in under domain credentials instead of just the Administrator Login. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.